# Response was of incompatible type - TypeError: "Bulk response of wrong dimension"

Tags: rust, redis

I am using this code to recieve the redis stream data:

```
pub fn consume(){
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open("redis://default:123456@127.0.0.1:6379/1").expect("get redis client failed");
    let mut con = redis_client
        .get_connection()
        .expect("get redis connection failed");
    
    let stream_name = "texhub-server:proj:s-comp-queue";
    let stream_id = "0";
    loop {
        let result = con.xread(&[stream_name], &[stream_id]);
        if let Err(e) = result.as_ref() {
            println!("{}", e);
            return;
        }
        let unwarp: Vec<(String, String)> = result.unwrap();
    }
}
```

when parse the redis stream response, always shows error:

```
Response was of incompatible type - TypeError: "Bulk response of wrong dimension" (response was [bulk(string-data('"texhub-server:proj:s-comp-queue"'), bulk(bulk(string-data('"1693881638829-0"'), bulk(string-data('"name"'), string-data('"test"'))), bulk(string-data('"1693881702534-0"'), bulk(string-data('"name"'), string-data('"test"'))), bulk(string-data('"1693891547874-0"'), bulk(string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'), string-data('""'))), bulk(string-data('"1693892469370-0"'), bulk(string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'), string-data('""'))), bulk(string-data('"1693892476263-0"'), bulk(string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'), string-data('""'))), bulk(string-data('"1693899506942-0"'), bulk(string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'), string-data('""')))))])
```

I have tried to tweak the response to `Vec<(String, Vec<(String, String)>)>` still did not match the response. what should I do to parse the stream response? the stream data look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the structure with indentation will probably help understand:

```
response was [
    bulk(
        string-data('"texhub-server:proj:s-comp-queue"'),
        bulk(
            bulk(
                string-data('"1693881638829-0"'),
                bulk(
                    string-data('"name"'),
                    string-data('"test"')
                )
            ),
            bulk(
                string-data('"1693881702534-0"'),
                bulk(
                    string-data('"name"'),
                    string-data('"test"')
                )
            ),
            bulk(
                string-data('"1693891547874-0"'),
                bulk(
                    string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'),
                    string-data('""')
                )
            ),
            bulk(
                string-data('"1693892469370-0"'),
                bulk(
                    string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'),
                    string-data('""')
                )
            ),
            bulk(
                string-data('"1693892476263-0"'),
                bulk(
                    string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'),
                    string-data('""')
                )
            ),
            bulk(
                string-data('"1693899506942-0"'),
                bulk(
                    string-data('"c98f73bc869143d084eb38a0fc38a8e7"'),
                    string-data('""')
                )
            )
        )
    )
]
```

This is also shown in the CLI output demonstrated in the documentation for [`XREAD`](https://redis.io/commands/xread/).

At the top level there is an array of elements, where each element has a key (i.e. a stream name) and a value (i.e. the stream contents). And each element in the stream content has a key (e.g. `1693881638829-0`) and then the data (e.g. `{"name":"test"}`).

So you are missing at least one level of nesting. If you want the quick way, this should work:

```
Vec<(String, Vec<(String, (String, String))>)>
```

Though you may wish the top-level to be a map-like structure and you may need a different datatype than `(String, String)` if the data being passed is not as simple as your sample data shows.